# ReactiveMongo scala null

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

An easy one I guess. When executing on the mongo shell:

```
db.topic.find({"user_id":ObjectId("52e39be16700006700d646ad"), "post_id":null})
```

It will list all topics where post_id either is null or does not exist. This works fine.

However when using Scala code I try following which doesn't work:

```
val cursor = db("topic").find(
  BSONDocument("user_id" -> user.id),
  BSONDocument("post_id" -> null)).cursor[Topic]
cursor.collect[List]()
```

Basically I have to change the condition BSONDocument("post_id" -> null). But how?

Many thanks!
Marcel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mongo shell query you have one JSON document that defines the query clause, but in Scala code you have 2 JSON documents, so the second document defines projection just like it would in Mongo shell. Here is `def find[S, P](selector: S, projection: P)...` [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/nightly/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.collections.default.BSONCollection). You need to make a single document with two fields out of your two docs like this:

```
val cursor = db("topic").find(
  BSONDocument("user_id" -> user.id, "post_id" -> null)).cursor[Topic]
cursor.collect[List]()
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! This works for me: BSONDocument("user_id" -> user.id, "post_id" -> BSONNull).